Copying Multiple Rows from a list of records to clipboard in PowerApps
I am looking to use the copy() function in PowerApps as a workaround for copying a list of ID numbers directly to clipboard in PowerBI. I am new to the PowerApps and am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here.
ForAll( Filter(Gallery3.AllItems,Not(IsBlank('BOL#'))), Copy('BOL#'.Text) )   
Can anyone help point me in the right direction?
I saw some discussion about collecting items in a gallery with checkboxes, but ideally I could create 1 button that could copy the entire list to clipboard with 1 click.
ForAll( Filter(Gallery3.AllItems,Not(IsBlank('BOL#'))), Copy('BOL#'.Text) )   
Returns only one value
ForAll(PowerBIIntegration.Data,Copy('Load ID_Column1'.Text))
Error
Copy('SO#'.Text)
Returns only one value

Power Apps has the Concat function which makes combining strings from a table much easier.
For your case, you can try something like this which will copy a specified field from all rows in your gallery separated by a comma:
Copy(Concat(Gallery3.AllItems, ColumnToCopy & If(!IsBlank(ColumnToCopy), ",")));

Alternatively, you can separate all values with a new line:
Copy(Concat(Gallery3.AllItems, ColumnToCopy & If(!IsBlank(ColumnToCopy), Char(10))));

Just be sure to swap out ColumnToCopy with your BOL field.
